# Can no longer access my Azure subscription after client adds me as admin to their account

Tags: azure

My client recently tried to add me as an Admin on their Azure account using the following steps:

- Go to portal.azure.com
- Search for subscriptions and select the subscription you want to give access to.
- On the left-hand side, click on Access Control (IAM)
- Click Add
- Add permissions blade will appear
- Select the role you wish to assign and type in the email address. The user will be notified via email.

I found these steps on: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/add-change-subscription-administrator?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support

I got the invite email and followed the directions.

Now I am receiving an error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfMJm.png

I also get this error in my notifications but I am not sure if it is relevant:

> Experiencing authentication issues The portal is having issues getting
> an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
> Additional information from the call to get a token: Extension:
> Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog Resource: microsoft.graph Details:
> AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider
> 'https://sts.windows.net/612fdf9c-07b8-4c70-9c09-9b3163713792/' does
> not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the
> application 'c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c'(Azure Portal) in
> that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the
> tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active
> Directory user account. Trace ID: 963f0a6c-185a-41ae-a3a3-c2dfcdfb0400
> Correlation ID: 4ee02d4f-ee80-4912-8406-7e047fb4bf1b Timestamp:
> 2020-12-15 22:28:58Z

I cannot access my subscription that I had dating back to Bizspark. I can only access my client's subscription. Furthermore, when my client logs in to his account it says he has no subscriptions.

How do we get our respective subscriptions back to normal? Can the accounts be rolled back to a previous state?

Azure support told me to clear my cache which I did and have not received any more help from them.

I am desperate for help!

Thanks, Justin.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

First, to access your old subs you need to switch the tenant you are looking at in the portal, currently you are looking at the clients tenant, which does not have your subs. Click on the "directory and subscriptions" menu in the top right and select your tenant. You should then see your subs.

The second issues is with access to your clients sub. The client needs to create your user as a guest user in their AAD tenant as documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I view the directory + subscriptions menu I see my client's, which for some reason is the default, and I see two directories with my name. My client's directory has his subscription but neither of my directories have a subscription.